# android - How can create video from onPreviewFrame?

Tags: java, android, media, android-mediacodec

In my application I need to record video and audio is not important. so far I used mediarecorder, but because of its delay I decided to changed it. after some search I understood that I can get data of surface from onPreviewFrame but it gives me byte array. I found out that with mediacodec I can change those byte array to video but there isn't any complete code or tutorial on this. How should I implement it? (I know that it's possible from android 4.3)

Comment: https://github.com/google/grafika . Bear in mind that MediaCodec is a relatively "raw" interface to the media encoder hardware. If you want to keep things simple, stick to MediaRecorder.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, good luck with it. MediaCodec has a very unpredictable nature across various devices. See the CameraToMpegTest example on this site:

http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/

as a start.

Comment: it's really big and complicated. isn't there any simpler example ?

Comment: You can have a look at this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html